Problem filtering products using comparison and logical operators in JavaScript
As I filter products from an API using JavaScript's filter() method, I cannot obtain the desired range of products defined by price checkboxes in HTML. The filering works when using an if statement like:
if ((product.price < checkboxesValues[j][1]))

but there is no filtering if I try to use a range such as:
if ((product.price >= checkboxesValues[j][0]) && (product.price <= checkboxesValues[j][1]))

, or
if (checkboxesValues[j][0] <= product.price <= checkboxesValues[j][1])

I am using this as a helper function. Code below:
html:
<!-- Price Checkboxes-->
 <div class="price-checkboxes">
  <h4>Price: </h4>
  <input type="checkbox" id="price1" name="price1" value="0,200">
  <label for="price1">0-200 EUR</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="price2" name="price2" value="200,400">
  <label for="price2">200-400 EUR</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="price3" name="price3" value="400,600">
  <label for="price3">400-600 EUR</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="price4" name="price4" value="600,800">
  <label for="price4">600-800 EUR</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="price5" name="price5" value="800,1000">
  <label for="price5">800-1000 EUR</label><br>
 </div>

javascript:
const isInCheckboxRange = (products) => {
  //create a NodeList of the selected checkboxes
  const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
  console.log("checkboxes: ", checkboxes);

  //transform the NodeList into an Array of the selected checkboxes
  const checkboxesArray = Array.from(checkboxes);
  console.log("checkboxesArray: ", checkboxesArray);

  //map the values in the Array into a new Array just with the selected checkboxes values in integers
  const checkboxesValues = checkboxesArray.map((checkbox) => {
    //return a number array from the previous string's value
    const stringArray = checkbox.value.split(",");
    return stringArray.map(Number);
  })
  console.log("checkboxesValues: ", checkboxesValues);

  const filteredProductPrices = products.filter((product) => {
    for (let j = 0; j < checkboxesValues.length; j++) {
      // console.log("product price: ", product.title, product.price, "checkboxesValues[j][0]: ", checkboxesValues[j][0], "checkboxesValues[j][1]: ", checkboxesValues[j][1]);

      if ((product.price < checkboxesValues[j][1])) {
        // if ((product.price >= checkboxesValues[j][0]) && (product.price <= checkboxesValues[j][1])) {
        // if (product.price > checkboxesValues[j][0] && product.price < checkboxesValues[j][1]) {
        // if (checkboxesValues[j][0] <= product.price <= checkboxesValues[j][1]) {
        console.log("product price: ", product.title, product.price, "checkboxesValues[j][0]: ", checkboxesValues[j][0], "checkboxesValues[j][1]: ", checkboxesValues[j][1]);
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  });
  console.log("Filtered Products: ", filteredProductPrices);
  return filteredProductPrices;
}

I tried to use the return true; statement in different parts of the nested loop but with no success.

If you've indeed narrowed the problem to a specific if condition, can you update the question to include a [mcve] which demonstrates this problem, hard-coding known data as needed?

Please don't comment out the code that your question is about.

It seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/3ot8zv1e/6/

Your code as written looks fine for me as well

Hello, I will review the code and check if there is anything else that is stopping my filtering. Thank you Barmar for reproducing it with your products. If I don't find the answer I will get back to you with the whole code and hard-coded data as David suggested. Thank you!

Give up on checkboxesValues[j][0] <= product.price <= checkboxesValues[j][1]. From left to right the first comparison produces a boolean which is converted to a number for the second comparison. Boolean false converts to 0 (zero) and true converts to 1 (one), which makes the expression true for all non-zero values;

It seems you like might be looking for Array#some which will allow you to use a clear AND clause and will exit early on success. const filteredProductPrices = products.filter((product) => checkboxesValues.some(([low, high]) => product.price >= low && product.price <= high)). I'm fairly sure this is a duplicate.

possible duplicates: Filtering Object Array with a Given Range, Javascript Filter and Some on Array of Objects

Thank you @traktor for clarifying that. Now I understand why, when I use this if statement, all the 20 products in my example are displayed (because they all have non 0 values).

That syntax for chained conditions works in Python, but not most other languages.

Thank you @pilchard, your solution worked for me. I had a problem with other filters that were in a "combinedFilters() function", which were not allowing the price filter as a helper function to work properly. After adding your line of code to the the combined filter, it worked:
const filteredProducts = products.filter((product) => {return  (selectedCategory === product.category || selectedCategory === "all") && (pattern.test(product.title)) && (checkboxesValues.some(([low, high]) => product.price >= low && product.price <= high) || checkboxes.length < 1);

All the answers were correct. But I'd like to vote on @pilchard answer as the one that helped me. Unfortunately it seems that I still can't vote. Anyway, thank you so much for your help.
